# How to split the header row to make new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposing I have a df like this,

```
uid | 202012AP   | 202012CAN  | 202012CASA | 202012total  | 202101AP   | 202101CAN  | 202101CASA | 202101total  |...
A1  |   0        |   1        |   10       |    11        |     1      |   2        |   0        |   3          |...
A2  |   1        |   8        |   99       |    108       |     4      |   5        |   1        |   10         |...
B1  |   0        |   1        |   99       |    100       |     2      |   3        |   2        |   7          |...
```

I want to be able to generate output df like the following,

```
uid | no     | reg  | amount
A1  | 202012 | AP   |   0
A1  | 202012 | CAN  |   1
A1  | 202012 | CASA |   10
A1  | 202101 | AP   |   1
A1  | 202101 | CAN  |   2
A1  | 202101 | CASA |   0
A2  | 202012 | AP   |   1
A2  | 202012 | CAN  |   8
A2  | 202012 | CASA |   99
A2  | 202101 | AP   |   4
A2  | 202101 | CAN  |   5
A2  | 202101 | CASA |   1
```

and so on..

Is there a pandas library to achieve this task? Any help would be really appreciated.

P.S. I actually don't need **01total** or **02total** cols to use in the output df but I provided it since that is the df have.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a combination of [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
# create long df using melt, cols is just an intermediary column
res = df.melt(id_vars='uid', value_name='amount', var_name='cols')

# remove total rows
res = res[~res['cols'].str.endswith('total')]

# concat the two new columns no and reg with the previously melted df
res = pd.concat((res.drop('cols', 1), res['cols'].str.extract(r'(?P<no>\d+)(?P<reg>\w+)')), axis=1)

# sort both columns and rows to match the expected output
res = res.sort_values(['uid', 'no', 'reg'])[['uid', 'no', 'reg', 'amount']]

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   uid  no   reg  amount
0   A1  01  reg1       0
3   A1  01  reg2       1
6   A1  01  reg3      10
12  A1  02  reg1       1
15  A1  02  reg2       2
18  A1  02  reg3       0
1   A2  01  reg1       1
4   A2  01  reg2       8
7   A2  01  reg3      99
13  A2  02  reg1       4
16  A2  02  reg2       5
19  A2  02  reg3       1
2   B1  01  reg1       0
5   B1  01  reg2       1
8   B1  01  reg3      99
14  B1  02  reg1       2
17  B1  02  reg2       3
20  B1  02  reg3       2
```

Notice that we also use [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) as an intermediary step:

```
res['cols'].str.extract(r'(?P<no>\d+)(?P<reg>\w+)'))
```

this is using a regex with [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) to directly create columns with names.

Comment: thanks for your input, may I know what would be the regex in this case? I edited the question a bit..I tried your answer but I get an error 'bad character in group name 'no' at position 4' ...I think it's because of the regex maybe (?P<no>^(2[01]|[2-9]|[0-9]))

Comment: @royalewithcheese The regex of the answer works with the new data, no need to change it

Comment: yeah, i understand! thanks for being so helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Idea is convert `iud` to `index` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first, then create `MultiIndex in columns` by [`Index.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('uid')
df1 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.str.endswith('total')]

df1.columns = df1.columns.str.extract('(\d+)(\w+)').set_index([0,1]).index
df1 = df1.rename_axis(['no','reg'], axis=1).stack([0,1]).reset_index(name='amount')
print (df1)
   uid  no   reg  amount
0   A1  01  reg1       0
1   A1  01  reg2       1
2   A1  01  reg3      10
3   A1  02  reg1       1
4   A1  02  reg2       2
5   A1  02  reg3       0
6   A2  01  reg1       1
7   A2  01  reg2       8
8   A2  01  reg3      99
9   A2  02  reg1       4
10  A2  02  reg2       5
11  A2  02  reg3       1
12  B1  01  reg1       0
13  B1  01  reg2       1
14  B1  01  reg3      99
15  B1  02  reg1       2
16  B1  02  reg2       3
17  B1  02  reg3       2
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df.set_index('uid')
df1 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.str.endswith('total')]

df1.columns = df1.columns.str.extract('(\d+)(\w+)').set_index([0,1]).index
df1 = df1.rename_axis(['no','reg'], axis=1).stack([0,1]).reset_index(name='amount')
print (df1)
   uid      no   reg  amount
0   A1  202012    AP       0
1   A1  202012   CAN       1
2   A1  202012  CASA      10
3   A1  202101    AP       1
4   A1  202101   CAN       2
5   A1  202101  CASA       0
6   A2  202012    AP       1
7   A2  202012   CAN       8
8   A2  202012  CASA      99
9   A2  202101    AP       4
10  A2  202101   CAN       5
11  A2  202101  CASA       1
12  B1  202012    AP       0
13  B1  202012   CAN       1
14  B1  202012  CASA      99
15  B1  202101    AP       2
16  B1  202101   CAN       3
17  B1  202101  CASA       2
```

Comment: thanks for your input, may I know what would be the regex in this case? I edited the question a bit..I tried your answer but I get an error 'bad character in group name 'no' at position 4' ...I think it's because of the regex maybe (?P<no>^(2[01]|[2-9]|[0-9]))

Comment: @royalewithcheese - testing, please give me some time.

Comment: sure, fyi 'no' can range from {current year}&{current month} and 'reg' can be either 'AP', 'CAN', 'US', 'EU', 'CASA'

Comment: @royalewithcheese - So now my solution create `no` column for numeric values and `reg` for non numeric after numbers, so in changed data working well. Just tested.

Comment: so what changed in your previous vs your current ans?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - no change, working well original solution with new data. But just tested your new regex

Comment: @royalewithcheese - For me working `df1.columns = df1.columns.str.extract('^(2[01][2-9][0-9][01][0-9])(AP|CAN|US|EU|CASA)').set_index([0,1]).index`, if using original solution it working for me too.

Comment: yeah, i understand! thanks for being so helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Keep only the relevant columns:

```
box = df.filter(regex="uid|0[1-2]reg.")
```

Create a dataframe by splitting with a regular expression

```
cols = (
    pd.Series(box.columns)
    .str.split("(reg.)", expand=True)
    .iloc[:, :2]
    .fillna("") # this allows easy melting on "uid"
    .set_axis(["no", "reg"], axis="columns")
)
```

Assign `cols` as a MultiIndex to `box.columns`:

```
box.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(cols)
box


no  uid                 01                       02
reg     reg1    reg2    reg3    reg1    reg2    reg3
0   A1     0    1         10    1          2    0
1   A2     1    8         99    4          5    1
2   B1     0    1         99    2          3    2
```

Now you can [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
box.melt("uid")

uid no  reg value
0   A1  01  reg1    0
1   A2  01  reg1    1
2   B1  01  reg1    0
3   A1  01  reg2    1
4   A2  01  reg2    8
5   B1  01  reg2    1
6   A1  01  reg3    10
7   A2  01  reg3    99
8   B1  01  reg3    99
9   A1  02  reg1    1
10  A2  02  reg1    4
11  B1  02  reg1    2
12  A1  02  reg2    2
13  A2  02  reg2    5
14  B1  02  reg2    3
15  A1  02  reg3    0
16  A2  02  reg3    1
17  B1  02  reg3    2
```

**UPDATE** (06/01/2021):
A *simpler*(opinion mine) abstraction is possible with the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
 # install latest dev version
 # pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
  import janitor
df.filter(regex="^(?!.*total)").pivot_longer(
    index="uid",
    names_pattern="(\d+)(.+)",
    names_to=("no", "reg"),
    values_to="amount",
    sort_by_appearance=True,
)

    uid no     reg  amount
0   A1  202012  AP      0
1   A1  202012  CAN     1
2   A1  202012  CASA    10
3   A1  202101  AP      1
4   A1  202101  CAN     2
5   A1  202101  CASA    0
6   A2  202012  AP      1
7   A2  202012  CAN     8
8   A2  202012  CASA    99
9   A2  202101  AP      4
10  A2  202101  CAN     5
11  A2  202101  CASA    1
12  B1  202012  AP      0
13  B1  202012  CAN     1
14  B1  202012  CASA    99
15  B1  202101  AP      2
16  B1  202101  CAN     3
17  B1  202101  CASA    2
```